# Docker will not open the page for me through Rider

Tags: docker, rider

This is how I use Rider from jetbrains to just like set Docker to start building and running my application.

Right now as it is I am working on running only such that When I click on my Docker in Rider (jetbrains) then build it and start my application up without any problems.

When I start pressing run on application then it does it without any problems to build etc. But the problem as it is right now that it

That it does not start the page up at all.

Below you can see the picture with Docker where there is a message when it is finished.

[image: Docker build success]

Here you can see what my setup looks like for my Docker.

And here can u see command `docker build -t onlinekursus . && docker run -p 8080:1 --name myapp onlinekursus docker run`

Thus, I have downloaded the plugin for Docker.

[image: Run/Debug]

The problem is then: Thus when it is successful at build and fine. But where the problem is right now is definitely to open the page and run it. As is right now, nothing happens if I go to localhost: 8080 So there are errors on the page.

Comment: Why are  you binding port 8080 to port 1?

Comment: For this giv me error `Failed to deploy 'myapp Dockerfile: Dockerfile': driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint myapp (f81583dbc7bbb5ad246ecfd9bd30413aa402e00bd651753efb765ed96fc27ae0):  (iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -A DOCKER -p tcp -d 0/0 --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:0 ! -i docker0: iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): Port 0 not valid\n\nTry `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.\n (exit status 2))`